# Support for Linux Mint v Ubuntu

Tags: mint

Which Linux OS has better user support IYO?

I haven't used linux in years but would like to use it again.

Comment: Here, on AskUbuntu, Ubuntu (non EOL) is supported. Mint is not.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)

Comment: Linux Mint *devs* don't have write/upload access to Ubuntu repositories, thus rely on a smaller set of packages that *replace* (via *inflated* package versions) the Ubuntu packages for many things, but as it'd require far more resources than they have available; rely on runtime *adjustments* for other changes; adding additional security attack vectors to the system. Linux Mint don't have a Security team vetting code etc. so it's security model is lower; and due to use of runtime *adjustments* when changes are made by Ubuntu problems can occur, ie. it's a different system to Ubuntu or *flavors*

Answer (score 2):

Both distros have forums, but Ubuntu has a bigger community over Mint. That means a lot more people to talk to over any issues you might come across.